# AJAX loop through datatable for occurrences

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a datatable with some softwares and the operating system they work on, so a software can run on different OS at the same time, and I need to iterate through all the rows of that Datatable and get a statistic of how many times a project is executed on a platform. The table below is just to create an example, my data is coming from a database through a GET response and the table is being populated by a JSP foreach method described below.

```
<p id="date_filter">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_from" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="From:">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_to" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="To:">
</p>


<button onClick="calculateStatistics()">Click!</button>

<select class='filter' id="select">
  <option value="">All softwares</option>
  <option value="">software1</option>
  <option value="">software2</option>
  <option value="">software3</option>
  <option value="">software4</option>
</select>

<select class='filter' id="selectWindows">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="">winXp</option>
  <option value="">win7</option>
  <option value="">winVista</option>
  <option value="">win10</option>
</select>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>software name</th>
      <th>windows version</th>
      <th>CreatedDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 3</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 2</td>
      <td>winVista</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>win7</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 1</td>
      <td>win10</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>software 4</td>
      <td>winXp</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    function calculateStatistics() {

   var selectPlatformCheck = document.getElementById("selectWindows");
   var selectPlatformSelected = selectPlatformCheck.options[selectPlatformCheck.selectedIndex].value;
      //projects
      var software1 = "";
      var software2 = "";
      var software3 = "";
      var software4 = "";

      //platforms
      var win10 = 0;
      var winXp = 0;
      var win7 = 0;
      var winVista = 0;

      
      if(selectPlatformSelected !="") {
          for(var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++){
            if(selectPlatformSelected != "") {
                if(selectPlatformSelected == "win10"){
                    win10++;
                }
                else if(selectPlatformSelected == "winXp"){
                    winXp++; 
                }
                else if(selectPlatformSelected == "win7" ){
                    win7++; 
                }
                else{
                    winVista++; 
                }
            }
          }
      }
      
  }
  
  </script>
```

Clicking on the button "Click" I need to create a new html page on which I'm printing, for each project, how many time a project runs on a platform, for instance:

```
software1 runs: 
2 times on win10
1 time on winXp

software2 runs:
1 time on win7
1 time on winVista

software3 runs:
1 time on win10
1 time on winXp

software4 runs:
2 times on win10
1 time on win7
1 time on winXp
```

In the future I will need to implement a pie chart or something similar, but it's not necessary now. Is there a way to implement my code in AJAX? I can even replace the content of the current page in Ajax, if necessary.
Thank you very much

EDIT: I'm getting the data from a Database - that I can't touch - and the JSP code I'm using for the generation of the table is the following:

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>softwares</th>
<th>Windows</th>
<th>CreatedDate</th>
</tr>
</thead>




<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${projects_retr}" var="projects">
<tr>
<td>${projects.Id}</td>
<td>${projects.softwares}</td>
<td>${projects.Windows}</td>
<td>${projects.CreatedDate}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Where do you get your data that generates the html?  Is it a static html `<table>` that you hand-edit for every change?  If not (and shouldn't be) then your statistics should come from the source data - and will be much easier to formulate in a system designed for it

Comment: My table is generated dinamically directly through a GET response from a server using jsp's 'foreach'  function. I didn't place the code because otherwise I couldn't have a working example

Comment: The point is that you have source data - so your "new html page" should be based on *that* data, not by parsing the `<table>` in your first page.

Comment: I created some scripts to parse the datatable with jquery and javascript, I can count lines and select rows, but I can't create statistics like I described. Is it possible to perform statistics from that datatable, store them into an array and draw that array in AJAX in a table on the same page?

Comment: @freedomn-m I've added the JSP code I'm using for the retrieving and generation of the data and the creation of the datatable using jquery. How can I implement that AJAX code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I modified the approach using the JSON parsing logic and implementing a double for loop for: iterating the rows and increasing the counter for each project